# iOS: is there a category of CAAnimation, which can auto resume its animation when app enters foreground again?

Tags: ios, animation, categories, foreground, resume

As almost each page in my app includes some animations, every time the app entered foreground again, many of the animations on the current page stopped. I have looked for some solutions, which all need management for each animation individually and may bring so much replicated extra code.

So is there a category of CAAnimation, which can auto resume its animation when app enters foreground?